# YA fiction 1980 - society living in underground caverns

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dystopia

I’ve read through many of the similar questions but I have not found the answer and I have more details. I’ve been looking for this book for almost 30 years.

The main character is a youth and I believe a female human. Might be a male.
One day, at school the kids are asked to draw a picture (it is implied that it’s some type of assessment). The main character draws the head of the societies leaders as a spider or in a web while in a relaxed state. (Subconsciously) We understand this is not appropriate - criticism of leaders.

The society has many tunnels that run through the outer area of the living area (I don’t recall the living spaces to be squalid in anyway). The tunnels are filled with water. They are never mapped which allows each new generation of people to have the pleasure of discovering something new.

It turns out the main character is special in that she is dissatisfied and feels something is being kept from her people by the leaders. I believe the story concludes with the fact that she is supposed to lead the ridged community back to the scary topside.

If you know this story - I’d love to give it to my daughter for Christmas this year.

P.s - I remember that the people have no hair. They’re naturally bald down on their heads.

I also recall that the main character eventually meets a girl with long blonde hair from the top side. (Which is why I wonder if the main character was actually male). That may happen in the first book or there may have been a second book in the set.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Partial match is '[Devil on my back](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1190712.Devil_on_My_Back)' and the sequel 'Dream catcher', especially if some elements are conflated.

Both novels involve colonies of humans who survived some sort if disaster in arcs, which are largely underground. Tomi, the male protagonist of the first book, escapes a riot but falls through the waste system into a river and ends up meeting escaped slaves. The rulers of the arc are hairless, but intentionally, not naturally.

In the sequel, Ruth is in arc three, which developed telepathic talents. She draws a spider as you describe in a class when picturing the web - the telepathic bond between them - with the heads of the four leaders.

Ruth dreams of arc one and leads a group to find them. She helps to free Tomi and the others from the rule of the computer that oversees arc one, and reunites him with the escaped slave, Rowan, who he fell in love with; she has red hair rather than blond, but her hair was emphasised in the plot.

At the end, Tomi, Ruth, and Rowan are encouraging the colonies to learn to live together and leave the arcs to live outside.

Comment: I kept interpreting "arc" as "story arc", although I think you intended "Arcology" or even "Ark"

Comment: Thank-you Micheal for your considered answer. It sounds like it might be a match. I’m going to see if my library has it and if not; I’ll hunt it down else where.

Comment: This is it!! Monica Hughs. How could I have forgotten. Yes; I did conflate a lot of details. Well points to you good sir, you’ve solved my decades old mystery. 

Comment: @Peter M - almost certainly arcology, but 'Arc' is the term used in the novels.